# Add and remove vtkChartXY/vtkContextView within a QVTKWidget renderer

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I currently have a Qt `MainWindow`, which holds a number of controls including a `QVTKWidget`. I can easily add a `vtkChartXY` object using a `vtkContextView` to the `QVTKWidget`:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkContextView> m_2Dview = vtkSmartPointer<vtkContextView>::New();
m_2Dview->SetRenderWindow(this->QVTKWidget->GetRenderWindow());
```

However, once I have it in the `QVTKWidget`, I can not find a way to return to the 3d view. I tried using the `vtkContextActor`, but it led to interaction issues. However, I'm willing to try out any suggestions if the `vtkContextActor` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to resolve this was to reset the `vtkrenderer` on the `vtkrenderwindow` by removing the `vtkrenderer` from the pointer of the `vtkRenderWindow` after storing the `vtkRenderer` pointer first, and then added the renderer I had stored back into the `vtkRenderWindow`.

This reset the view for me at least and below is the snippet I used.

`AnalysisWindow` is my pointer to the actual `vtkRenderer`.

```
if(AnalysisWindow != NULL)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> win;
    win = AnalysisWindow->GetRenderWindow();
    win->RemoveRenderer(AnalysisWindow);
    win->AddRenderer(AnalysisWindow);
}
```

Comment: I'll have to give that a shot when I have a chance to look into it, thanks!